# Soundcloud: What Is going wrong with this Oauth2 request?

Tags: oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I have been trying to using oauth2 authentication with an api key.

i'm tracing out every step of the way. Its successfully getting a token, but then giving a 401 error when I try to access https://api.soundcloud/me.

```
oauth2.RoundTrip: credentials found 
 map[
     access_token:1-156891-51311-fec80e6e640f49007
     scope:non-expiring expires_in:0
 ]

oauth2.Get response: 
401 Unauthorized 401 HTTP/1.1 1 1 
 map[
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:[Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin] 
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:[GET, PUT, POST, DELETE] Date:[Tue, 27 Oct 2015 02:12:17 GMT] Server:[am/2] 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*] 
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers:[Date] 
    Cache-Control:[private, max-age=0, must-revalidate private, max-age=0]
    Content-Length:[0]] 0x18d47bc0 0 [] false map[] 0x18d880e0 0x18cbd440
 ]
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might happen? The same problem is not happening with other providers such as github. I am using github.com/stretchr/gomniauth for authentication.